# Choose if your number is a fraction or a decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, decimal, fractions

I'm trying to make it so if the denominator of the fraction is over 2, it prints the decimal. Else, it prints the fraction

```
from fractions import Fraction
z = float(input())
frac = (Fraction(z))
s = str(z)
x = s.find("/")
x1 = x + 1
segment = z[x1:]
print(segment)

if len(segment) <= 3:
    print(frac)
else:
    print(z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it way harder than it needs to be. Use the [`denominator` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.denominator) of the `Fraction` instance:

```
frac = Fraction(z)
if frac.denominator > 2:
    print(z)
else:
    print(frac)
```

You may want to use the [`Fraction.limit_denominator()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) to account for the imprecise nature of floats:

```
frac = Fraction(z).limit_denominator()
if frac.denominator > 2:
    print(z)
else:
    print(frac)
```

`Fraction.limit_denominator()` finds the closest fraction to the original where the denominator is limited be below 1 million:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> 2/3
0.6666666666666666
>>> Fraction(2/3)
Fraction(6004799503160661, 9007199254740992)
>>> Fraction(2/3).limit_denominator()
Fraction(2, 3)
```

Another alternative is to pass the user input straight to `Fraction()`; the constructor accepts both valid values for `float()` *and* strings in the form of *numerator / denominator* (with optional sign). This would let your users input exact fractions such as *'2 / 3'*:

```
z = Fraction(input()).limit_denominator()
if frac.denominator > 2:
    print(float(z))
else:
    print(frac)
```

Comment: I'd also not convert the input to a float before giving it to Fraction. That'd avoid the kind of things floats cause issues with and would enable input such as "7 / 2" as well.

Comment: @JonClements: perhaps, but using `limit_denominator()` also can compensate for that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the `Fraction.limit_denominator` does @MartijnPieters

Comment: @EliasFiz: it returns a new `Fraction()` object that is as close as possible to the absolute value of the original but with the denominator limited to a given value (the default is 1 million). This usually makes for a much better representation. Compare `Fraction(2/3)` with `Fraction(2/3).limit_denominator()`. The first produces `Fraction(6004799503160661, 9007199254740992)`, while the latter gives you `Fraction(2, 3)`, a much more "human" representation of the `0.6666666666666666` float value.